# Fourier Transform of the conjugate of a complex function

Tags: homework, soft-question

Given that $x(t)$ Fourier Transforms to $X(f)$. What happens when you Fourier Transform $x^*(t)$, and your $x(t)$ and $x^*(t)$ are both complex functions??

Comment: Look up the complex conjugation property of the Fourier Transform. This is a common analysis technique.

Comment: What happens when you change $j$ into $-j$?

Comment: This question appears to be homework. Complete answers to homework are off-topic, but specific questions about homework are acceptable if they include enough detail. Please edit the question to include more background about what you don't understand.

Answer (score 2):

$\mathcal{F}\{x^*(t)\} = X^*(-f)$

Taken from the table of Fourier transform theorems on slide 6 of this document: [https://www.comm.utoronto.ca/~dkundur/course_info/316/KundurFTProperties_handouts.pdf](https://www.comm.utoronto.ca/%7Edkundur/course_info/316/KundurFTProperties_handouts.pdf)

Tables like these are useful in general. Please look it up yourself next time! :)

Comment: the $-f$ was not correct.  it's **either** negate $f$ **or** conjugate $X(f)$, but not both.  all you're doing when you conjugate $x(t)$ is swapping $j$ and $-j$ everywhere.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson you made it wrong. shredEngineer had it perfectly right. Compare https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform#Conjugation

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson I agree with Jazzmaniac

Comment: i agree with Jazz, too.  i had it wrong.  although $j$ and $-j$ are swapped in $x^*(t)$, they are not in the $e^{-j2 \pi f t}$ factor in the Fourier Transform integral.  but if $t$ is swapped with $-t$ in $x^*(t)$ and not in $e^{-j2 \pi f t}$, does that finagle it back again?

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson Please don't grab your left ear with your left hand by wrapping your left arm around your head first. There is no need to reverse time, why not write $$\exp(-j2\pi ft) = \exp(-(-j)2\pi (-f)t)$$ which shows that $f$ gets negated and the final answer is the complex conjugate of what we had previously: $\mathcal F\{x^*(t)\} = X^*(-f)$ exactly as shredEngineer wrote.